# Center text vertically while occupying the whole containing view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

In React Native, I have a `Text` element contained within a `View`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Buy this!
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: '#77EB11'
  },
  paragraph: {
    backgroundColor: '#F55008',
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  },
});
```

I want the text to be centered both horizontally and vertically. Normally, this would be achieved by using `justify-content` and `align-items` in the containing `View`. However, I am working on Windows and because of [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/1516), I also have the constraint that the `Text` must occupy the whole `View`, otherwise I will not be able to click the whole `View` when I will put a callback in it, later.

I also created a [React fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/97628/) with the exact same problem, but which may be easier to use.

Currently, the text is centered only vertically. How can I center it horizontally as well?

Again, the most important constraint is that the `<Text>` tag should occupy all of the containing `<View>`.

Comment: One easy method would be to set `lineHeight: "200px"` on the text, but that only works if you know the size of the parent container and the text occupies a single line.

Comment: That applies to my case. I tried it in React Native on Windows. However, it seems to have no effect. Do you need to add anything else except `lineHeight: "200px"` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- `display: table;` on the container
- `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` on the paragraph.

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/yekj9xe6/1/)

```
const styles = {
    container: {
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      backgroundColor: '#77EB11',
      display: 'table'
    },
    paragraph: {
      backgroundColor: '#F55008',
      textAlign: 'center',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      display: 'table-cell',
      verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
};
```

If you want to look at other strategies on how to align text vertically, try taking a look at this article [**ALIGN TEXT VERTICALLY**](http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/)

Comment: Your solution is great, but on the line `display: 'table-cell'`, I am getting: `Invalid value 'table-cell' for type 'Facebook.Yoga.YogaDisplay'. Parameter name: value`